# Push only if property is defined

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to fix this condition to remove `title` from pushing in else part (instead of passing an empty string)?

```
photos.push({
    title: (this.display_photos[index].title ? this.display_photos[index].title : ''),
    href: this.display_photos[index].path+this.display_photos[index].name,
});
```

So if the condition in `title` is not satisfied, I would like to push `href` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
const photo = {
  href: this.display_photos[index].path+this.display_photos[index].name,
}

if (this.display_photos[index].title)
  photo.title = this.display_photos[index].title

photos.push(photo)
```

Comment: This code solves my problem. However, as I am pretty new at this, will defining `const` mean that it's gonna stay there as long as the application is running? If that's so, could I define it as `var`?

Comment: This means you can not assign a new value to the variable. var is best not to use, if you do not like const, you can also use let.

Comment: It's not about liking `const`, I'm gonna use it, I was just curious what it's lifetime is :)

Comment: All variables will stay in memory as long as the application is running and they are still in use so the garbage collection does not remove them. So defining a value as const, let or var has no effect on its 'lifetime'.

Comment: @Shilly thank you on explanation! And what about `var`, why is it "best not to use"?

Comment: It's about variable scope. var is scoped to the nearest function, while in other programming languages they are scoped to the closest block. This confuses people coming from other languages. So javascript was updated to also support let and const, which are also scoped to the nearest block. So it's not really 'best not to use', it's more 'const and let are less confusing'. But if you understand the difference between function scope and block scope, it does not really matter. I prefer using const for almost everything since it helps preventing bugs.

Comment: @niksrb you can read more [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6).

Comment: I was programming in C# for few years, and now everything in JS is new to me. In my company, `var` is used the most, but  as I do understand the difference between function scope and block scope, I guess it will be okay to use `var` in my example.
Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to create an if/else condition to check if title is defined like this:

```js
const title = this.display_photos[index].title
const href = this.display_photos[index].path+this.display_photos[index].name

if (title) photos.push({ title: title, href: href });
else photos.push({ href: href });
```